# Batch - Read a text and insert a line into a variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a watchdog for a server and it need some configs so I want to make a separate text file and in this text file the structure will be:

```
map: arena
difficulty: hardcore
```

and more, I want to read the text file and find a specific line and "store" it into a variable.

But, I don't know how...

Comment: I searched a lot on Google and I found like how to read a text file and that's it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "file_path=c:\file.txt"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=: " %%m in ('find /i "map" "%file_path%"') do set "map=%%m"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=: " %%d in ('find /i "difficulty" "%file_path%"') do set "difficulty=%%d"


echo difficulty/map : %difficulty%/%map%
```

?

and you need to change the `file_path`  to point to your file

Comment: If the text file is in the same folder as the batch file what do i set for the file_path variable ?

Comment: @Briant just the name of the file.The full path won't be necessary .